# How to list more than 200 tracks of a user using Soundcloud python API

Tags: python, soundcloud

I am a newbie to Soundcloud programming and Python. I am trying to get the list of all the tracks from a user. I am able to get only 200 tracks although there are more than 200 tracks in the user's account. I am using python. I tried to see if there is a "next_href" attribute and there wasn't one.
Here is a snippet

```
print client.get('/me').username
    tracks = client.get('/me/tracks')
    if(hasattr(tracks,"next_href")):
        print "Has another page!!!!!!!!!"
        print next_href
    for track in tracks:
        print unicode(track.title).encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found that there is an offset parameter that can be used to offset the starting track.

```
tracks = client.get('/me/tracks',offset=200)
```